# How to create right nested loops?

Tags: c++

> An array is given for 15 values. Take the absolute values for every three numbers in the array, going one after the other, and calculate the area of a triangle with sides, the values of which correspond to the taken numbers. Create a new array in which to enter the values of the resulting areas. Display all areas on the screen:

I know how to calculate the areas, etc. But I don't know how to organize right nested loops.

Could you explain it?

My example:

```
int numbers[15]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   
    }   
}
```

Comment: You need only one loop `for (int i = 0; i < 15; i += 3)`. Inside that loop use `numbers[i]`, `numbers[i + 1]`, and `numbers[i + 2]` as side values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using a single loop. I think if you reviewed my solution, then you can do it using nested loop.

```
double ans[10];
for(int i=0, j=0;i<15;i+=3, j++){
    double s=(double)(numbers[i]+numbers[i+1]+numbers[i+2])/2;
    double area = sqrt(s*(s-numbers[i])*(s-numbers[i+1])*(s-numbers[i+2]));
    ans[j]=area;
}
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) cout<<ans[i]<<endl;
```